# Wiring jquery file upload to google app engine

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, image-processing

I'm trying to add visual drag-and-drop upload capabilities to my GAE-based site using the JQuery File UPload plugin ( see https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki ). While there is a documentation page on the topic ( https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Google-App-Engine ), it falls short of showing the whole process and no matter how much I wrestle this around I cannot get it to work.

My starting point is a simple single file image upload to the blobstore which redirects to a list of images:

```
class Pic(db.Model):
    blob_key = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
    url = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    creation = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class PicUploadForm_Handler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_pic/')
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
        self.response.out.write("""Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit" 
        name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>""")

class PicUpload_Handler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        pic = Pic(
            blob_key=blob_info.key(),
            url=images.get_serving_url(blob_info.key()))
        pic.put()
        self.redirect('/pics/list/')

class List_Pics(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        pics = Pic.all()
        pics.order("-creation")
        results = pics.fetch(5)
        html_str = '<html><body>'
        for pic in results:
            html_str += '<div><a href="%s"><img src="%s"/></a></div>'%(pic.url, pic.url+'=s100')
        html_str += '</body></html>'
        self.response.out.write(html_str)
```

Now the Image Plugin has two parts on the client-side which may require customization:
This one:

```
<script>
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    add: function (e, data) {
        var that = this;
        $.getJSON('{{upload_url_1}}', function (url) {
            data.url = url;
            $.blueimpUI.fileupload.prototype
                .options.add.call(that, e, data);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

and the upload form:

```
<form action="{{upload_url_2}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
        <label class="fileinput-button">
            <span>Add files...</span>
...
```

After wrangling with this for a day, I cannot figure out what is the role of each one of those urls (`{{upload_url_1}}` and `{{upload_url_2}}` in that last snippet).

I have tried hooking one of them to a handler which handles the uploads and returns json with the results, and hook the other one to the handler which allocates the upload url (using `create_upload_url()`) but any permutation of this type of wiring failed.

Can anyone with experience wiring jquery image upload into GAE python can provide an explanation or a full example?

Answer (score 1):

`upload_url_2` looks like it should correspond to `create_upload_url()`.

`upload_url_1` looks like it would be invoked as a callback when a file has been selected, before it gets uploaded. If you're not actually trying to accomplish something here, you may be able to omit it. Have you tried initializing it without an `add` callback, just `$('#fileupload').fileupload();` ?

Comment: this is one of the permutations I tried, but it does not work